# Vendoring Golang Shared Repository

Tags: go

Trying to move to the officially supported Golang vendoring solution from legacy Godeps workflow.

Scenario:

```
Repo A===
         \
           ========> Repo C (shared library code)
         /  
Repo B===
```

What is the best workflow I can choose for a mid-size (roughly 5-10 member) team of engineers to vendor Repo C for both Repo A and Repo B? Engineers of varying abilities, most of which probably shouldn't need to know the details of this at all?

I'm currently using govendor for this. I'd prefer not to switch but would if there is a tool that provides a better workflow.

This needs to integrate with a CI server running the builds. I can think of 3 scenarios:

Vendor Repo C into A & B:

- Pros:

  - Reproducible Builds
  - Easy integration with CI
- Cons:

  - Manual and Error Prone - Can easily vendor incorrect code
  - Engineers need decent knowledge of vendor tool and methodology

Symlink Repo C trunk branch into vendor folders of A & B:

- Pros:

  - Engineers need no knowledge of vendor tool
  - Low Developer Maintenance
- Cons:

  - Builds not (easily) reproducible
  - Possibility of including code in build that shouldn't be released
  - Less Flexible (Repo A and Repo B can't have differing versions of C)

Include Repo C as a git submodule or subtree in Repo A and Repo B (either utilizing vendor or not):

- Pros:

  - Engineers need no knowledge of vendor tool
  - Easy Setup
  - Less Maintenance
  - Reproducible Builds
- Cons:

  - Having to use git submodule or subtree

Finding surprisingly little about this question on the internet.  Is there some idiomatic way of doing this?  I'm sure there are other ways of doing this; what am I missing?

Comment: You could take a look at [vendetta](https://github.com/dpw/vendetta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest to use a manifest based approach with version constraint.

```
Project A == Manifest
             |- Repo A@~1.0.1
             |- Repo B@~1.0.1

Repo A == Manifest
             |- Repo C@~1.0.1

Repo B == Manifest
             |- Repo C@~1.0.5

Repo C == Manifest empty
```

Which will resolve into

```
Project A == Resolved Manifest
             |- Repo A@1.0.1
             |- Repo B@1.0.1
             |- Repo C@1.0.5
```

where `~1.0.1` means `>=1.0.1 <1.1.0`.

As you see B and A dependency to C are independent, yet within project they are resolved correctly.

In the event A and B would define incompatible dependency to C, an error should occur as the project should not be build-able.

You may prefer to use caret `^` rather than tilde `~`, `^1.0.1` -> `>=1.0.1 < 2.0.0`.

Note that you are not forced to use those 'helpers' such tilde and caret, you may define explicit version range.

You shall decide which constraint to apply given the level of confidence you give to the remote author to correctly upgrade its version number.

Finally,you can use glide to solve that for you.

Starting with Repo C, assuming you already tagged the repos, run `glide init`, `git commit -am 'glide init'`, `git push`

Repo A, `glide init`, `glide get git@repo.com/repoc`, `git commit -am 'glide init'`, `git push`

Repo B, `glide init`, `glide get git@repo.com/repoc`, `git commit -am 'glide init'`, `git push`

Finally, Project A, `glide init`, `glide get git@repo.com/repoa`, `glide get git@repo.com/repob`, `git commit -am 'glide init'`, `git push`

To re install the project, `glide install`, `go build`.

Nothing prevent you to tarball ProjectA with its vendor folder, in order to skip the glide install command when you execute the remote installation.

But you normally don t want to commit the vendor folder for a development environment. You d usually add `vendor/` to your `.gitignore` file and run `glide install` or `glide update`.

Expect some difficulties in the begin, passed that step, things will work.

Once you jumped to that workflow, note that you ll have to bump every changes on your repos.

That is bloatware when you work both project A and repo B to reach a viable change, so in that case, rather than vendoring repoB into project A (you can leave the manifest definition, but get ride of the repoB folder into vendor/), install repoB as a `go` module with the `go get` command. 
Doing so the changes are taken in effect immediately on re-build. Once the change set is completed, browse into each repos and bump them appropriately.

Finally you may want to use a version bumper to help you to get it done quick and fast, it happens i did [one](https://github.com/mh-cbon/gump) for my personal usage.

hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great answer.  It seems the "what am I missing" comment is answered by "glide" :-)  It seems to make package management much more like node or python, which is amenable to me.

I"m going to give this a whirl.  I think your suggestion will suffice for my need, but I'm going to try it out and wait before i mark it answered.

Thank you!

Comment: Glide, specifically using the "mirror" functionality, was exactly what I was looking for.  You can mirror a repo to a local folder and work on it as if it was in the same path.  You just need to remember to run `glide update` after you change the shared library for the project you're working on.